# How to create subfield keyword for Aggregation in ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get Aggregation results from ElasticSearch index

For exmaple , values in my index

```
"_source": {
"ctry": "abc", 
"totalentry": 1,
"entrydate": "2022-01-06"
},
"_source": {
"ctry": "abc", 
"totalentry": 3,
"entrydate": "2022-01-07"
},
"_source": {
"ctry": "xyz", 
"totalentry": 1,
"entrydate": "2022-01-08"
}
```

expected Results should be get totalentry based on country

```
ctry : abc
totalentry : 4
ctry : xyz
totalentry : 1
```

My Aggreagtion query

```
  QueryBuilder querybuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("entrydate")
                .gte("2022-01-01").lte ("2022-01-31"));      
      TermsAggregationBuilder groupBy = AggregationBuilders.terms("ctry").field("ctry");
      SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                        .withQuery(querybuilder).addAggregation(groupBy)
                        .build();
       List<Sample> records = elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Sample.class);
```

Above aggregation query returning 3 records instead of 2 aggregated results.
My index properties

```
"ctry": {
"type": "keyword"
```

How to change it to below , so that i hope i will get correct aggregation results

```
ctry": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"ignore_above": 256,
"type": "keyword"
}
}
}
```

My java code

```
@Document(indexName="sample", createIndex=true, shards = 4)
public class Sample { 

     @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
     private String ctry;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of Spring Data Elasticsearch. The `queryForList` variants were deprecated in 4.0 and have been removed in 4.2.

You need to use one of the `search...()` methods that return a `SearchHits<Sample>>` object. That will contain the documents for your query **and** the aggregations.

Comment: i am not able to see search method in elasticsearchRestTemplate. so using resthighlevelclient i am trying like below. but search results is having only count of data. to get sum of data again i need to add sum aggregation? looks in this approach we need to write multiple lines of code to prepare query and reading response. Is there any other way. writing query in mustache file and reading it inline will be a good approach?

Comment: searchReq= new SearchRequest(sample"); rangeQuery = ...rangeQuery("entrydate").gte(fromDate).lte(toDate);searchSourceBr.query(rangeQuery);TermsAggrnBuildr aggrnBuilder = AggrnBuilders.terms("ctry").field("ctry");searchSrcBr.aggrn(aggregationBuilder);      searchReq.source(searchrcBr); searchRes = restHighLevelClient.search(searchReq,..);SearchHit[] hits=searchRes.getHits().getHits();Terms ctryAgg =searchRes.getAggregations().get("ctry");ctryAgg.getBuckets().stream().forEach(ctrybkt -> {Sample res = new Sample();res.setCtry(ctrybkt.getKey());  //for getting totalentry one more aggregation});

Comment: `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` implements the `SearchOperations` interface (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.3.1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/SearchOperations.java). Which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch version 2.2.0 release

Comment: That means Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x, that's out of maintenance since October 2020. No `SearchHits` there - as far as I remember there was a possibility to write a custom parser for the response and extract it there. But I'd strongly advice to update your dependencies.